# How to crete Bold text with a new line of normal text in the same cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to create this format of cell which is Bold and normal in the same cell and different line.

This is the actual code I working on

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$objBold = $objRichText->createTextRun('some number');
$objBold->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objBold->getFont()->setSize(10);
$objRichText->createText('\nsome text');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue($objRichText);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true)->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
```

But the result are still in the same line  " **some number**\nsome text"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=newline+phpexcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Strings 101

`\n` needs to be in Double quotes (`"`) not single quotes (`'`) if you want it to be interpreted as a new line, and not as a literal `\n`

```
$objRichText->createText("\nsome text");
```